# Make object Steady problem in certain part of Animation

Tags: animation, rigging

I’m fairly new to blender and I was working on creating simple backpack animation for my unreal game.

In my game, backpack will be always attached on my character’s “spine_05” bone. So I need an animation but it must be Child of “spine_05” in whole keyframes of animation.

In Blender, I set parent of backpack and I made an animation

[image]

But I have problem here, I want to make steady Backpack object, as you see in the red circle from 45th to last keyframe. I shouldn’t break child contraint or modify its influence in the animation.

This is blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wEoN01s8A8lc4W96A1e3JpJzkaB14KQp

Comment: may i ask why you cannot change/keyframe the influence? because that's exactly the use case of influence: To "unchild" temporarily the child constraint. And this is obviously what you want in that case. But if you exclude the obvious "solution" as prerequisite...it will be difficult to solve your problem.

Comment: As I mentioned, this animation will be always played on character's spine as a child. So I couldn't break child constraint. If i do, I have to break on the game engine too and I don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Backpack bone, set a child of bone constraint targeting the spine bone and set the backpack child of the new bone (do not confuse object constraints with bone constraints).

Then program the animation in Blender, using the influence slider when needed (use the "Copy World Space" addon for fast programming).

Then select the new bone in pose mode, go to menu Pose > Animation > Bake action (Only selected, Visual keying, Clear constraint, Overwrite current action), so to end up with a clean animation without relying on constraints and influence sliders.

Comment: I don't fully understand you, it's probably because I'm new to blender. Could you please apply to blend file your said?